# remove shadow from input type checkbox in chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

How can I remove box shadow from an input type checkbox.

```
< input type="checkbox" name="run" value="" style="" >
```

Basically I want to transform

[image]

to

[image]

I tried different ways like border,outline, box-shadow etc but none worked in case of type checkbox.
Any handy css for this or any other way?
Please note that this is for an app which uses chromium engine so, I want this to work on Google Chrome only.

Comment: @downvoter mind telling reason b4 downvoting?

Comment: Some people just having fun down-voting anyone , i hope Stackoverflow community can resolve this issue (voteup)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my solution , I used to hide the actual checkbox and then replace it with a div with the required design ,  also made the needed script to make the checkbox work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.control--checkbox').click(function() {

      if ($('#mycheckbox').is(':checked')) {
        $('#mycheckbox').attr('checked', false);
      } else {
        $('#mycheckbox').attr('checked', true);
      }
    }

  );
});
```

```css
.control input {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
}

.control__indicator {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 0;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.control input:disabled~.control__indicator {
  opacity: 0.6;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.control__indicator:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

.control input:checked~.control__indicator:after {
  display: block;
}

.control--checkbox .control__indicator:after {
  left: 8px;
  top: 4px;
  width: 3px;
  height: 8px;
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="control-group">

    <label class="control control--checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" id="mycheckbox" checked="checked"/>
      <div class="control__indicator"></div>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that's exactly what I was thinking.  great work with .control__indicator

Comment: @JerryGoyal Glad to help you Sir

Comment: @JerryGoyal would you accept this as a solution please

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by Neji solution I made a little easier version of a custom checkbox.
It uses no images so it is scalable and customizable. The user can get the value of custom checkbox by `$('#id_of_custom_checkbox').val()` -> `true`/`false`

HTML:

```
<div>

            <div id='mycheckbox' class='custom-checkbox'>
                <div class='custom-tick'></div>
            </div>

            <span>I agree</span>

        </div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.custom-checkbox').click(function (e) {
        toggleCustomCheckbox(e.target);
    })
});

function toggleCustomCheckbox(el) {
    var tickEl = $(el).find('.custom-tick').addBack('.custom-tick');
    if (tickEl.css('visibility') === 'hidden') {
        tickEl.css('visibility', 'visible')
        $('.custom-checkbox').val(true)
        alert('you ticked me')
    } else {
        tickEl.css('visibility', 'hidden')
        $('.custom-checkbox').val(false)
        alert('you un-ticked me')
    }

}
function setCustomCheckbox(checkboxid, val) {
    var tickEl = $(checkboxid).find('.custom-tick').addBack('.custom-tick');
    if (val && val === true) {
        tickEl.css('visibility', 'visible')
        $('.custom-checkbox').val(true)
    }
    else {
        tickEl.css('visibility', 'hidden')
        $('.custom-checkbox').val(false)
    }
}
```

CSS:

```
.custom-checkbox{
    border: solid 2px orange;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-o-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
  }
.custom-tick{
    border: inherit;
    display: inherit;
    cursor: inherit;
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 8px;
    width: 5px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    border-left: 0;
    border-top: 0;
    border-width: 2px;
    margin: 0px 0px 3px 4px;
}
```

Here's the working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/JerryGoyal/xr62yara/8/

Answer (score -1):

```
input[type="checkbox"]{
  height: 140px;
  width: 140px;
 -webkit-appearance: unset !important;
  border: 1px solid red;
}


<input type="checkbox" >
```

Just unset the appearance of checkbox. But then on check you have to do a workaround.

Working Fiddle here  https://jsfiddle.net/d2tfo790/

Comment: i'm not able to 'tick' your checkbox

Comment: You will not be able to thats what i told you. You will not be able to modify the default look of a checkbox. Either you have to create a mask over it and make it look like a checkbox.